# Why is the number of decimals not correct when I truncate it to 2 and why isn't it the correct percentage

Tags: python, python-3.x, percentage

I need help with this function.

```
def expenses(monthly_budget):
    expenses = float(input("What are your actual expenses each month? "))
    perc_act_expenses = expenses / monthly_budget
    perc_act_expenses = round(perc_act_expenses, 2)
    print(f"Your actual expenses are {expenses} and that is {perc_act_expenses * 100}% of your monthly budget.") 
    rec_expenses = .50 * monthly_budget
    rec_expenses = round(rec_expenses, 2)
    print(f"Recommended amount spent on expenses each month is ${rec_expenses}\n")
```

When I put 100000 as the salary and calculate the net income after fed and state tax for FL I get 85000. The monthly budget is 85000/12 = 7083.33

This is what I get as the output:
What are your actual expenses each month? 8000
Your actual expenses are 8000.0 and that is 112.99999999999999% of your monthly budget.
Recommended amount spent on expenses each month is $3541.66

-It should only round to 2 decimal points and it doesn't
-I'm expecting an output of 112.94

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is floating point math broken?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-floating-point-math-broken)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you did the first rounding of `perc_act_expenses`, you have already lost some precision, and so when you multiply that with `100`, it won't be as exact (also, you're not rounding the result of the multiplication). You should calculate the percentage first, and then round it like so:

```
>>> expenses = 8000.0
>>> monthly_budget = 7083.33
>>> round(100 * expenses / monthly_budget, 2)
112.94
```

Also, since you're using f-strings, you could round with them like so:

```
>>> print(f'Your actual expenses are {expenses:.2f} and that is {100 * expenses / monthly_budget:.2f}% of your monthly budget.')
Your actual expenses are 8000.00 and that is 112.94% of your monthly budget.
```